# How to conditionally modify exports from an ES6 Javascript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow still access the module exports of an ES6 module from within the module, like you do in CommonJS with module.exports.

For clarity, I have a js module (**Config.js**) that I use to export all of my config variables like so.

```
export const DatabaseName = "myDbName";
export const DatabasePort = 3000;
export const DatabaseHosts = ["174.292.292.32"];
export const MaxWebRequest = 50;
export const MaxImageRequests = 50;
export const WebRequestTimeout = 30;
etc...
```

And then I have a separate **Dev.Config.js** file which only holds the overrides for my dev environment.

```
export const DatabaseHosts = ["localhost"];
export const DatabasePort = 5500;
```

In my main **Config.js** file, I have this logic at the bottom.

```
try {
    var environmentConfig = `./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.Config.js`;
    var localConfig = require(environmentConfig)
    module.exports = Object.assign(module.exports, localConfig)
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error overriding config with local values. " + error)
}
```

And then finally, in my consuming code, I'm able to just import my config.js file like so

```
import * as Config from "./Config.js";

console.log(Config.DatabaseHosts) // Gives me the correct "overridden" value on my dev environment
```

Currently I've been using babel to transpile my code all back into CommonJS which I guess is how I'm able to sort of mix and match import/export syntax, and still reference module.exports like I've done above.

My question is, how would I replicate this pattern in a pure ES6 module without needing to transpile this using babel where I cannot modify my module.exports from within the module itself?

Comment: Is it important to not use an existing configuration solution?

Comment: Such as? It seemed like such a trivial bit of code that I didn't consider using some other configuration solution. But if there's a commonly used option out there, I'm open to it. Still curious though from a purely academic standpoint how the above pattern might be replicated in pure ES6.

Comment: Just use dynamic imports and top level await if your node version supports that. The rest are hacks. Export a promise from your main config module. Trust me, we have the same name ;)

Comment: @Morgan Recommendations are OT but the canonical one is `dotenv`. There are others (dotenv is ok, a cpl others are similar-but-different and worth looking at).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional exports isn't a supported pattern in ESM.

In order to modify exported values using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) from another module whose specifier is derived from an environment variable (in a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement so that a failed attempt won't throw an uncaught exception at the top level), you can modify the structure of your exports so that they are exposed as properties on an object. Below is a reproducible example to demonstrate:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-77465699",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=Dev node main.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node main.js"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`./Dev.Config.js`:

```js
export const Config = {
  DatabaseHosts: ["localhost"],
  DatabasePort: 5500,
};

export default Config;
```

`./Config.js`:

```js
const Config = {
  DatabaseName: "myDbName",
  DatabasePort: 3000,
  DatabaseHosts: ["174.292.292.32"],
  MaxWebRequest: 50,
  MaxImageRequests: 50,
  WebRequestTimeout: 30,
};

try {
  // Import a module specifier based on
  // the value of the NODE_ENV environemnt variable.
  // Destructure and rename the default export:
  const { default: envConfig } = await import(
    import.meta.resolve(`./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.Config.js`)
  );

  // Iterate the keys and values, updating the existing Config object:
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(envConfig)) {
    Config[key] = value;
  }
} catch (cause) {
  console.log(`Error overriding config with local values: ${cause}`);
}

export { Config, Config as default };
```

`./main.js`:

```js
// Import named export:
import { Config } from "./Config.js";

// Alternatively, since it's also the default export:
// import { default as Config } from "./Config.js";

// Or, using syntax sugar:
// import Config from "./Config.js";

console.log(Config.DatabaseHosts);
```

In the terminal:

```txt
% node --version
v20.9.0

% npm run dev

> so-77465699@0.1.0 dev
> NODE_ENV=Dev node main.js

[ 'localhost' ]

% npm run prod

> so-77465699@0.1.0 prod
> NODE_ENV=production node main.js

Error overriding config with local values: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/node/so-77465699/production.Config.js' imported from /Users/node/so-77465699/Config.js
[ '174.292.292.32' ]
```

Comment: Why not wrap the try/catch in an async setup function and then `export default await setup()`? I mean why not use top level await? Otherwise looks like race conditions when reading config values.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891?noredirect=1#comment136568214_77465891) @morganney I don't understand your question… top level await **is** used. And what would be the purpose of wrapping the existing code in a function — only to immediately invoke it and export the awaited return value?

Comment: Where is it being used? Are you sure… You’re exporting a pojo.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891?noredirect=1#comment136568253_77465891) @morganney Yes — it is used in the `try` block just before the dynamic `import()`.

Comment: Sure you are making async calls as a side effect of import but will that make consumers wait for the promise to finish before being able to read values?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891?noredirect=1#comment136568269_77465891) @morganney Yes, and the example demonstrates that — do you see the output from the terminal?

Comment: I see that you have added some terminal output, which could literally be anything you wanted to enter. I'm asking because it is interesting to see that top level await is working for consumers when the module exports are not a promise themselves, but instead dependent upon another top level await within the same module. I have never used this pattern for top level await, so when I find the time I'll have to confirm for myself. I am still skeptical ;)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891?noredirect=1#comment136568318_77465891) @morganney The terminal output is copied and pasted verbatim: you should see the same exact outputs when reproducing the example. This [top-level `await`](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) article on the V8 website (in particular, the [module execution order](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await#module-execution-order) section) has information that should be helpful.

Comment: No need to check out the article, I just wrote a quick script to confirm for myself that it does indeed work, thanks though. I think in this case since the export itself is really dependent upon the async work, my **personal preference** is to define the export once that work is complete, even though top level await works regardless of how the export is written.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891#comment136568393_77465891) @morganney Would you have found it more intuitive if the existing `export` declarations were not present, and — instead — a single one were at the end of the module like this? `export { Config, Config as default };`

Comment: Perhaps. Doing async work after the `export default` line is what violated my personal preferences and "felt wrong", but as we've been discussing, consumers of a module using top level await will receive the module's public API **after async work has completed**, as desired, and **regardless of whether the export happens before or after the async tasks**. It's as if modules using top level await get wrapped in one big `async function`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77465699/how-to-conditionally-modify-exports-from-an-es6-javascript-module/77465891?noredirect=1#comment136568640_77465891) @morganney Thanks; I've updated the answer to use that syntax in effort to help avoid potential confusion in other readers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to build/overwrite the exports object dynamically in ES6 modules. Even the conditional import will already require either top-level `await` or tooling support.

What you can do however is mess with `let` declarations and `eval`:

```
export const DatabaseName = "myDbName"; // keep things as `const` to prevent overriding them
export let DatabasePort = 3000;
export let DatabaseHosts = ["174.292.292.32"];
export let MaxWebRequest = 50;
export let MaxImageRequests = 50;
export const WebRequestTimeout = 30;
… // etc

try {
    var environmentConfig = `./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.Config.js`;
    var localConfig = await import(environmentConfig)
    for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(localConfig)) {
        eval(`${name} = value;`);
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error overriding config with local values. " + error)
}
```

I would not recommend this though. Use this approach only if you cannot change how the *Config.js* module is used, or if there are too many exported variables for the alternatives to be feasible.

Instead, I would suggest you create a separate module that merges the configurations, though this requires spelling out the configuration names twice:

```
// Default.Config.js
export const DatabaseName = "myDbName";
export const DatabasePort = 3000;
export const DatabaseHosts = ["174.292.292.32"];
export const MaxWebRequest = 50;
export const MaxImageRequests = 50;
export const WebRequestTimeout = 30;
```

```
// Dev.Config.js
export const DatabaseHosts = ["localhost"];
export const DatabasePort = 5500;
```

```
// Config.js
import * as defaultConfig from "./Default.Config.js";

const localConfig = await import(`./${process.env.NODE_ENV}.Config.js`).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error overriding config with local values. " + error);
    return {};
});

export const {
    DatabaseName,
    DatabasePort,
    DatabaseHosts,
    MaxWebRequest,
    MaxImageRequests,
    WebRequestTimeout,
    … // etc
} = Object.assign({}, defaultConfig, localConfig);
```

Or change the configuration modules to default-export objects, which you can manipulate arbitrarily. You loose the ability to use named imports and get static validation though.

Comment: The evaluated string will not produce valid JavaScript (and will throw) if any key in the object is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, but if all the exports are defined with `export const …`, they will be valid identifiers, so I think this risk is acceptable (and the exception would be caught anyway). But I agree it's not a great solution and have already edited the answer to provide an alternative.